# Terraform kubectl provider manifest to specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, namespaces, kubectl

I am learning how to translate `kubectl` deployments to terraform. I am currently facing issues getting services to work as intended with terraform provider `kubectl` once I specify a namespace.

I have confirmed the terraform script works when doing the equivalent `kubectl apply` to the default `namespace`.

What is the proper methodology in terraform using the `kubectl` provider to `apply -n namespace`?

The two different approaches I have tried are:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "example" {
        override_namespace = kubernetes_namespace_v1.namespace.metadata[0].name
        yaml_body = file("${path.cwd},deploy.yaml")
    }
```

And also:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "example" {
        yaml_body = file("${path.cwd},deploy.yaml")
    }
```

with adding the namespace to the `deploy.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: namespace
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: namespace
```

Then when I try to confirm that the service is functioning as intended via:

```
kubectl logs example-6878fd468-9vgkm
```

> Error from server (NotFound): pods "example-6878fd468-9vgkm" not found

Comment: You need to specify the namespace in the logs command as well. ``kubectl logs example-6878fd468-9vgkm -nexample``.

Comment: DOH. yeah your right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terraform description is fine. You need to specify the `-n` switch to your `kubectl logs` command as well, to detect the pod in the right namespace.

```
kubectl logs example-6878fd468-9vgkm -nexample
```